# Can't make Vmware ESXi 6.7 LAG on top of Dell VLTi port-channel

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, configuration

So.

I've configured dell 5212F switches with 2x100G ports into VLTi domain. For some reason - when I run show vlt 10 mismatch it show that both of switches have no roles. But they appear as should in show vlt 10 and they able to ping each other mgmt IP

In addition - i've created a port-channel 1 with vlt-channel 1 and connected 2 25G uplinks to one of vmware servers.

I've created a distributed switch with LAG interface and assigned my 25G interfaces to that LAG (instead of uplinks to distributed switch). I've routed a vmk adapter to LAG interface and assigned proper VLAN everywhere (both in vmk and on distributed portgroup)

I see both links green (and up) - however I don't see port-channel 1 alive show vlt 10 vlt-port-details 1 , its just empty there.

So maybe someone have an experience with this and can advise what I'm missed?

Comment: Are you using the standard vSwitch on ESXi or a VDS? Only the latter supports LACP. (And you don't really need LAG with ESXi mostly.)

Comment: Distributed switch, thanks
Not a LAG, so what do you recommend?
I have 2 100G switches and i want to ensure connectivity in failure of 1 of switches.

Comment: VLT *is* LAG. Initially only proprietary, but also broader terminology for LAG in general on F10/Dell. vSphere VDS only supports LACP. Generally, I'd recommend against LAG with vSphere - it is usually more practical and stable to use adapter balancing and failover through port group settings.

Comment: So basically make VLT , but without LAG, just independent ports on aggregated switches?

Comment: The thing is that we also have vSAN, how is he feels with plain adapter balancing ?

Comment: L2 LAG is always about traffic distribution which rarely distibutes really well. Unless there's a hard reason that you really require aggregation I'd avoid it - you've got more control without. I'm not into the intricacies of vSAN but iSCSI works *way* better with separate adapters and proper multipathing. I used to run a mixed 1G/10G hosts and storage SAN that could easily go to the physical port limits in all combinations. I doubt that is possible with LAG.